# Material UI - backdrop triggers onClick on its children

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI backdrop and want to have some some tiny form inside of it. But whenever i click on its children the backdrop closes thanks to `onClick` which supposed to toggle the backdrop.

Is there any way how to stop backdrop `onClick` from triggering from inside backdrop (it's children) ?

I have tried to use `useRef` for elements inside but to me it seems crazy to have multiple referencies on elements and checking them in toggle function if it supposed to hide backdrop or not. Also i don't have access to some elements inside of the backdrop;

```
const handleBackdropToggle = e => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget === backdropRef.current);
  if (e.currentTarget === backdropRef.current) {
    setOpen(!open);
  }
};

const handleToggle = e => {
  setOpen(!open);
};
```

```html
<Backdrop
  className={classes.backdrop}
  open={open}
  onClick={handleBackdropToggle}
  ref={backdropRef}
>
  <div className={classes.form}>
    <CommonFormCard
      noBorder={true}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      onBack={handleToggle}
      submitButtonText={`Odeslat`}
    >
      <>
        <h4>Od kdy má fotograf nafotit nemovitost?</h4>
        <CommonForm formData={renderFormData} onChange={onChange} />
      </>
    </CommonFormCard>
  </div>
</Backdrop>;
```

Comment: If you look at the DOM structure you would find out that the `MuiBackdrop-root` actually covered the whole page. Maybe for your situation, the [material UI modal](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/) fits your demand better. You can take full control of it.

Comment: @kekai definitly possible solution. Just out of interest, what use has backdrop then ?

Comment: For some one-shoot, no UX bound, single notification message display I guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than toggling your backdrop via `onClick` on the backdrop, you can use the [Click away listener](https://material-ui.com/components/click-away-listener/#click-away-listener).

The main issue that you are likely experiencing is that you need to stop the propagation of click events in the form. The nature of DOM events is that they propagate up to all ancestors by default. You can prevent this with:

```
<div className={classes.form} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering late. But this solution may prove most efficient.

Don't use `onClick` of `Backdrop` component. Instead, add a child button to close the backdrop. Now you can trigger children click events without needing to worry about event propagation to the backdrop parent.